# Missing python on MinGW

Tags: python, gdb, mingw32, mingw-w64

I am trying to build gdb on Windows7 using Mingw. I am configuring it with "--with-python" flag. However, I get error:

```
configure:8898: checking for python 
configure:8916: found /c/Python34//python 
configure:8929: result: /c/Python34//python 
configure:9067: checking for python34 
... 
configure:9095: result: no 
configure:9278: error: python is missing or unusable
```

I suppose it may be due to that I am using 64-bit version of python, while the mingw is 32 bit. I tried to use [MinGW64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) but I do not find it useful - it does not support bash, and I can't use configure script.

Please, show the way to build gdb on mingw32 with python, or how to make MinGW usable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using msys2 to provide a 64bit (and 32bit if you so wish) gcc. 
This comes with bash and the standard coreutils